# Serpentine PCB heater size calculation

Tags: resistors, pcb-design, trace, serpentine-trace

So, I'm kinda new to the field and the time has come to design my first PCB heater. The main concept is to drive it using a Raspberry Pi and a temperature sensor as feedback.

Here is the whole procedure I followed in steps.

1. Since my AC/DC adapter outputs 12V/3A I need a heater around **4 ohms** in order to be efficient.
2. By using [this](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/01/31/pcb-trace-width-calculator/) trace width calculator and applying the following values I managed to get a result of **3.73 ohms** and a voltage drop of **11.2V**.

   ```
   current: 3Amps
   thickness: 35um
   temp rise: 65 (I want to be able to reach 90C)
   ambient temp: 25
   trace length: 7m
   ```
3. Given that I want a heater of **13mm width** I calculated the number of traces that will be created. Which is: \$trace\_length/heater\_width = 7m/13mm = 7000/13 = 538\ traces\$
4. Then by multiplying \$number\_of\_traces\ *\ trace\_separation = 538\ *\ 0.12mm(120um) = 64.56mm \ heater's\ length.\$
5. Finally, I have a heater with the following characteristics:

   ```
   length: 64.5mm
   width: 13mm
   trace width: 1.14mm
   trace separation: 0.12mm
   ```

I would like to mention here that in calculator's page there are results for internal and external layers. For my calculations, I used the values of the **internal layers** and I'm not sure if I did well. So what do you think? Is this procedure and calculations reasonable? Would you suggest a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

The calculator temperature rise figures are not going to be accurate- you'd be better off to use another method to estimate the rise of an isothermal plate the size of your PCB from the total **wattage**.

Copper has a positive temperature coefficient of about +0.39%/K so you'll have about 25% less power at 90°C, however you also should never exceed the maximum current output of your power supply, so  you probably should aim for a bit higher than 4 ohms. The copper thickness is also not all that well controlled, so unless you can adjust the voltage a bit you might want to be a bit cautious. You could add some taps to trim the cold resistance.

I get more like 3\$\Omega\$ @ 25°C from first principles using \$\rho\$ = 1.72E-8 \$\Omega-\text m\$ for the resistivity of copper  for 7m of 1.14mm wide 34.8um thick trace. That's probably worth looking into.

I didn't look at the other calculations- there will be some effect from the shape of the corners (sharp vs. radiused).

Comment: So, you suggest me to increase the total length of the trace in order to achieve a higher total resistance? e.g from 7m to go at 8m? Sorry for being that noobish but I'm just trying to understand the whole idea. Thanks